# selenium UI testing is not able to fill the pop up window to enter credentials

Tags: selenium

selenium UI testing is not able to fill the pop up window to enter credentials. There were suggestions to use autoit tool to fill the pop window. But looking if it can be achieved by Selenium itself. Please suggest

Comment: If you can't send_keys("absolutepath") then you have to use autoit.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass that authorization window that requires the user and password if you send them directly in the url like:

```
https://username:password@stackoverflow.com
```